# Functions of the form $e^\frac{\ln(p(x))}{p(x)}$

Tags: reference-request

Is there any literature surrounding functions of the form $f(x)=e^\frac{\ln(p(x))}{p(x)}=p(x)^{\frac{1}{p(x)}}$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial? By [graphical](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qmcxazziyt) methods, it seems as though $f(x)$ has a tendency to become tangent to $p(x)$. It'd be nice to see more (possibly detailed) analysis of these functions.

Comment: It is $[p(x)]^\frac1{p(x)}$ which tends to $1$ as $p(x)\to \infty$.